# How export more than 5000 rows from google analytics to an excel

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to export more than 5000 rows to an excel sheet from google analytics, but I am not able to do so. I have searched a lot about it in google andtried the url modification which replaces `explorer-table.rowCount%3D5000` with `explorer-table.rowCount%3D50000`. But it's not working for me. It still returns 5000 rows only. Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Here are some options to pull more than 5000 rows from Google Analytics.

1) Use the Google Analytics Query Explorer to pull 10,000 rows (API query max). Set the max-results to 10,000. Use the start-index to pull additional 10k row chunks (set start index to 10,001 then 20,001 then 30,001 etc.

2) Use the [Google Analytics Sheets Add-On](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on?hl=en) to pull 10,000 rows.

3) Use Python to pull data 10,000 rows at a time via the Google Analytics API. Here is a solution that will let you [pull over 1 million rows unsampled from Google Analytics using Python](http://www.ryanpraski.com/python-google-analytics-api-unsampled-data-multiple-profiles/).

4) Use an Excel Connector tool like Analytics Edge to pull up to 1 million rows of data from Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

As a fairly frequent GA user, I can confirm that the replacement of "D500" to "D100000" in the URL used to work fine for me, minus the occasional browser crashing, but now now matter what I change that value to, I still can only get a max of 5000 rows. Not sure when specifically, but  I'm pretty sure I was able to use the workaround ~6 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Very handy way to do this (from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/analytics/comments/ectf4d/tip_how_to_export_more_than_5000_rows_from_google/))

> Just recreate the report in Google Data Studio, hover over the table
> in View mode (not edit), click the 3 button menu and 'export as CSV'.
> It automatically fetched all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Google were recently pushing [Premium Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/premium/capabilities.html) at me, but at $150,000 per annum it's a non-starter. But I suspect, like the curse of data sampling (there's no sampling with Premium), they are endeavouring to make the free version slightly less usable by quietly putting a block on that old export modifier trick. It used to work fine for me, but no more.

Comment: Its still limited to 5000 rows in Premium Analytics version.

Comment: @moonboot The export functionality is the same on premium (capped to 5K rows) but if you have access to Premium, there is now (2016) an "unsampled report" functionality which you can use instead.