# How to increase google analytics row more than 10000 in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics-api

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py
i have tried this code. I can't get more than 10000 rows. Can you please help me?

Comment: Please see the link. i have used it to get data from google analytics. i am struggling to get more than 10000 rows

Comment: Hi Eshwar, have you tried looking for similar post as this seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142598/how-export-more-than-5000-rows-from-google-analytics-to-an-excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How export more than 5000 rows from google analytics to an excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142598/how-export-more-than-5000-rows-from-google-analytics-to-an-excel)

Comment: a = []
    for pag_index in range(0, 50):                                                                                                  a.append(service.data().ga().get(
                ids='ga:',
                start_date='2018-04-01',
                end_date='2018-04-30',
                dimensions = "ga:date,ga:dimension2",
                metrics='ga:pageviews',
                start_index=str(pag_index*10000+1),
                max_results=str(pag_index*10000+10000)).execute())
    return a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extra google analytics data day by day in the range of start and end date with more than 10000 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921087/extra-google-analytics-data-day-by-day-in-the-range-of-start-and-end-date-with-m)